# Build nested xml string with easier way

Tags: python

Build nested xml string with easier way.

I need to prepare the following string to request a demanding response,

How could I levage Python utils to finish this task more easier ?

Thanks

```
    {"strFlightXml":"<flights><flight><flight_id>{EC65FB6D-33C5-4CA6-BD96-93D37F4D0EA0}</flight_id><airline_rcd>MM</airline_rcd><flight_number>585</flight_number><origin_rcd>NRT</origin_rcd><destination_rcd>CTS</destination_rcd><fare_id>{721D8471-9DCE-47E8-B7B4-EC5E2FF51F00}</fare_id><transit_airline_rcd></transit_airline_rcd><transit_flight_number></transit_flight_number><transit_flight_id></transit_flight_id><departure_date>20160219</departure_date><arrival_date>20160219</arrival_date><arrival_day>5</arrival_day><departure_day>5</departure_day>
    <planned_departure_time>1455</planned_departure_time><planned_arrival_time>1640</planned_arrival_time><transit_departure_date></transit_departure_date><transit_departure_day></transit_departure_day><transit_arrival_date></transit_arrival_date><transit_arrival_day></transit_arrival_day><transit_planned_departure_time></transit_planned_departure_time><transit_planned_arrival_time></transit_planned_arrival_time><transit_airport_rcd></transit_airport_rcd><transit_fare_id></transit_fare_id><booking_class_rcd>S</booking_class_rcd><currency_rcd>JPY</currency_rcd></flight></flights>","strFlightType":"Outward"}
```

Answer (score 0):

It actually sounds like you need a *template engine*, like [`jinja2`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/) or [`mako`](http://www.makotemplates.org/). Create an *XML template* and render it passing into a dynamic context.

There is also [`lxml.objectify`](http://lxml.de/objectify.html) that moves the XML generation to a Python object level.